# AJAX not running success function

Tags: php, html, ajax

I've got an AJAX script that lets the user login on the login page however the script seems to stop after it runs the beforeSend.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#login').click(function() {
            var username=$("#username").val();
            var password=$("#password").val();
            var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
            if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "login.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){                                                                                         
                       $("#login").val('Connecting...');
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data) {
                            $("body").load("<?php echo $dom; ?>").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
                            window.location.href = "<?php echo $dom; ?>";
                        } else {
                            $('#shakeme').shake();
                            $("#login").val('Login')
                            $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                        }
                    }
                });
            } return false;
         });
    });
</script>
```

The AJAX script sends the data to login.php

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username=clean($_POST['username']); 
    $password=clean($_POST['password'])); 
    $sql = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE username='" . $username . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();
    $pass = $result['password'];
    $salt = getSalt($pass);
    $password = $salt . $password;
    $password = $salt . hash('sha256', $password);
    if(strcmp($pass,$password)==0) {
        $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the PHP script? Am I meant to return data somehow? This is my first time using AJAX.

Comment: What you want to send in ajax response from you php file??

Comment: you sure something is present in data.. there must be some data to run the success function. You are returning something there

Comment: Its because you were not returning any value from your `login.php` page

Comment: You have to return some value to the ajax function from the login.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return values from your `login.php` file as

**login.php**

```
if(strcmp($pass,$password)==0) {
     $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
     echo true;
}else{
     echo false;
}
exit;
```

and within **js**

```
success: function(data){
if (data == true) {
    $("body") . load("<?php echo $dom; ?>") . hide() . fadeIn(1500) . delay(6000);
    window.location.href = "<?php echo $dom; ?>";
} else {
    $('#shakeme') . shake();
    $("#login").val('Login')
    $("#error") . html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
}
}
```

Comment: Great this worked! Along with a few other silly bugs I had in the code